# Filter pandas dataframe on date from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following two tables. Notice the second table extends an additional 15 days into February:

```
dates1 = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('2018-1-1 00:00', '2018-1-31 23:59', freq='h'), columns=['date'])
dates2 = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('2018-1-1 00:00', '2018-2-15 23:59', freq='h'), columns=['date'])
```

I want to filter the second dataframe based on the most recent date from the first dataframe. Here I find the most recent date from the dates1 table. The result is a timestamp:

```
most_recent_dates1 = dates1['date'].max()
Timestamp('2018-01-31 23:00:00')
```

Then I try to filter the second table as follows:

```
dates3 = dates2[[dates2['date'] <= most_recent_dates1]]
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 1104.
```

How can I filter a table using one timestamp from another table and not get this error? I know I can do this with an inner join (pandas.merge), but there are times I don't want to use an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas dataframe indexing permits a Boolean series / array as an input. Therefore, you do not need to use a *list* of a series. You can index directly with a Boolean series:

```
dates3 = dates2[dates2['date'] <= most_recent_dates1]
```

As the error points out, you have provided an item of length 1, whereas it expects an item with the same length as your dataframe.

See [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) from the official docs for more information.

Comment: You're kidding me; it's that simple. I guess I never understood why the need for two brackets for filtering (e.g. df[[filtering conditions]]). I'll have to read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the same using apply function

```
dates2[dates2.apply(lambda x: x['date'] <= most_recent_dates1,axis=1)]
```